# Integrating Stripe in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a custom form with stripe, and while it all appears to be submitting, when I check my dashboard in Stripe, although I do see a record of the transaction - I do not see the amount or any reference to the cc coming through. With that said, I am not quite sure what I SHOULD be seeing in the dashboard. But I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong. Here is the code to my form:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row Row one">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
       <%= form_for @project, url: project_charges_path, :html => {:id => "payment-form"}, method: 'post' do |f| %>

            <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :@project_id, :value => @project.id %>

            <div class= "field">
              <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %><br>
              <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %><br>
            </div>

            <div class= "field">
              <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code (cvc)" %><br>
              <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %><br>
            </div>

            <div class= "field">
              <%= label_tag :card_month, "Expiration" %>
              <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
              <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"}%>
            </div>

            <div class= "actions">
              <%= f.submit("Submit") %>
            </div>

            <div id="stipe-error">
              <%= flash[:error] %> 
            </div>

      <% end %> 
    </div>
</div>
<!-- <div class="row"></div> -->
```

and here is my charges controller:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    def create

         @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
         binding.pry
          # Amount in cents, this is being read and recorded in stripe dashboard
          @amount = 500
          customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
            :email => 'helloWorld@stripe.com',
            :card  => params[:stripeToken]
          )

          charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
            :customer    => customer.id,
            :amount      => @amount,
            :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
            :currency    => 'usd'
          )

              @payment = Payment.create({
                user_id: current_user.id,
                project_id: @project,
                amount: @amount
                })
              @payment.save

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
    end

    # private
    # def charges_params
    #   params.require(:payment).permit(:comments, :user_id, :project_id)
    # end
```

end

Per a tutorial I have also included some javascript in my application.js:

```
$('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);
    alert('you clicked submit');
    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
  });

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
}
```

Inside the striped dashboard I see:

[image]

the email comes through, but nothing concerning the amount or card. I don't expect to see the card number persay, but some reference to it, maybe just the type, or last four digits? Also in the front page of the dashboard (the area what gives a graph, I think I should be seeing the sum of the payments, even test payments, and the sum is still $0 despite having  made over a dozen test payments of $5 each.

What am I missing here?

Also most of the tutorials I have come across are either really old, or PHP, which I am not familiar with. If anybody can recommend a great resource, that would really be helpful as well. I plan to use stripe for multiple projects, and would really like to UNDERSTAND it...

Answer (score 1):

I might be very late in replying and you must have already done this but just in case this might help some else. I have just integrated stripe in my app. I am not sure what you are asking but i think a working example might help. This is very similar to what you have done and i can't find what's going wrong.

What i'm doing is saving customer_id returned by stripe in my user table. When the user saves the credit card, a certain amount according to the subscription plan is deducted. You will see the customer_id in your plan details under the subscribers in the dashboard. Also, in the customers, When you refer that customer_id, you'll see what plan he's subscribed to.

View: (creditcard.html.erb)

```
<div class="row">
  <% if flash[:error].present? %>
  <div class="col-lg-12 alert alert-danger">
    <%= flash[:error] %>
  </div>
  <% else %>
  <div class="col-lg-12" id = "payment-errors">
    <span class="payment-errors"></span>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div>

  <%= form_tag plans_billings_chargecreditcard_path, id: "payment-form" do%>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Card Number</label>
        <%= text_field_tag nil, nil, size: 20, "data-stripe": "number", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>CVC</label>
        <%= text_field_tag nil, nil, size: 4, "data-stripe": "cvc", class: "form-control" %>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Expiration Date(MM/YY)</label>
        <select class="selectpicker set-width" data-live-search="true" data-stripe = "exp_month">
          <option>- Month -</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
          <option>6</option>
          <option>7</option>
          <option>8</option>
          <option>9</option>
          <option>10</option>
          <option>11</option>
          <option>12</option>
        </select>
        <select class="selectpicker set-width" data-live-search="true" data-stripe = "exp_year"> <!-- form-control input-lg -->
          <option>- Year -</option>
          <option>16</option>
          <option>17</option>
          <option>18</option>
          <option>19</option>
          <option>20</option>
          <option>21</option>
          <option>22</option>
          <option>23</option>
          <option>24</option>
          <option>25</option>
          <option>26</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= submit_tag "Save Card", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

CofeeScript: (plan_billings.coffee)

```
stripeResponseHandler = (status, response) ->
  # Grab the form:
  $form = $('#payment-form')
  if response.error
    # Problem!
    # Show the errors on the form:
    $('#payment-errors').addClass 'alert'
    $('#payment-errors').addClass 'alert-danger'
    $('.payment-errors').text response.error.message    
    $('.submit').prop 'disabled', false
    # Re-enable submission
  else
    # Token was created!
    # Get the token ID:
    token = response.id
    # Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
    $form.append $('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token)
    # Submit the form:
    $form.get(0).submit()
  return

$ ->
  $form = $('#payment-form')
  $form.submit (event) ->
    # Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
    $form.find('.submit').prop 'disabled', true
    # Request a token from Stripe:
    Stripe.card.createToken $form, stripeResponseHandler
    # Prevent the form from being submitted:
    false
  return
```

Controller: (in PlanBilling controller, chargecreditcard action)

```
@plan_and_billing = current_user.plan_billing
@current_plan = DataPlan.find_by(id: @plan_and_billing.data_plan_id)
token = params[:stripeToken]
if current_user.customer_id.present?
  customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.customer_id)
  customer.sources.create(source: token)
  redirect_to plans_billings_planbilling_path
else
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create( :source => token, plan: YOUR_PLAN_ID_YOU_HAVE_INYOUR__DASHBOARD  )
  @credit_card = current_user.update(customer_id: customer.id)
  redirect_to plans_billings_planbilling_path
end
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to plans_billings_creditcard_path
```

What's happening in controller is that when a user has no card and he saves the card details, the card is saved and the Price of the plan you have mentioned is deducted. And if he already has a credit card saved, and saving another one, the card will only be saved as you'll see in his details in the dashboard. The new card will not be charged. Its just for saving new credit card to that customer.

I still have a long way to go in this, and of course this might not be a very good code, but this is just very basic thing you might find helpful. In case someone tries it out and faces some prob, i'll be glad to help. Also, I'll be grateful if someone can guide me to make this code better. Cheers :)