# Error TypeError: can't dup NilClass - Stripe

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, webrick

I am getting an error `ERROR TypeError: can't dup NilClass` when processing a Strip charge. I have followed the rails stripe integration documentation.

The error from the terminal is:

```
    Started POST "/charges" for ::1 at 2016-05-27 12:35:48 +0100
Processing by ChargesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"URydkbi6DghMZnzVqbf79KU+YRy/T+9g3UQ8tO8HTXG4uqvEMzdm6V/EjseNiZiIPS3ziOJJTpJ1K+gGMipksg==", "stripeToken"=>"tok_18FjA2JxArkI2Z35Q4MB3sCE", "stripeTokenType"=>"card", "stripeEmail"=>"fergusmorton@live.com"}
[2016-05-27 12:35:48] ERROR TypeError: can't dup NilClass
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httprequest.rb:392:in `dup'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httprequest.rb:392:in `meta_vars'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 55ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Net::HTTPFatalError (500 "Internal Server Error "):
  app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:9:in `create'



Net::HTTPFatalError: 500 "Internal Server Error "
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:119:in `error!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:128:in `value'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:915:in `connect'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x86-mingw32/lib/restclient/request.rb:413:in `transmit'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x86-mingw32/lib/restclient/request.rb:176:in `execute'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x86-mingw32/lib/restclient/request.rb:41:in `execute'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/stripe-1.43.0/lib/stripe.rb:298:in `execute_request'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/stripe-1.43.0/lib/stripe.rb:196:in `execute_request_with_rescues'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/stripe-1.43.0/lib/stripe.rb:148:in `request'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/stripe-1.43.0/lib/stripe/api_operations/request.rb:15:in `request'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/stripe-1.43.0/lib/stripe/api_operations/create.rb:5:in `create'
        from C:/Users/Fergus/best-ever-me-v-1.1/app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:9:in `create'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.5/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

charges_controller.rb

```
    class ChargesController < ApplicationController
    def new
end

def create
  # Amount in cents
  @amount = 500

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :source  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'usd'
  )

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to new_charge_path
end
end
```

initiliazers/stripe.rb

```
    Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['SECRET_KEY']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

cart/show.html.erb

```
    <div class="shopping-cart" style="margin-top:160px;">
  <%= render "shopping_cart" %>
  <%= form_tag charges_path do %>
  <article>
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: €<%= current_order.subtotal %> </span>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="Cart Total"
          data-amount="<%= current_order.subtotal %>"
          data-locale="auto"></script>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**Updated log Following Michael's Suggestions.**

```
 Started POST "/charges" for ::1 at 2016-05-31 11:45:45 +0100
Processing by ChargesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qXPL5OhG1UA+Ui4uyB7+80/UGDGXFPnOevOf/kmZhitA1f2xY8u9oS3w3DzsIJ2P18eKpcoSWDzSnEtMlLSv6A==", "stripeToken"=>"tok_18HANXJxArkI2Z35encjc3uW", "stripeTokenType"=>"card", "stripeEmail"=>"fergusmorton@live.com"}
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, stripeTokenType
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `stripe_customer_id' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:15:in `create'



NoMethodError: undefined method `stripe_customer_id' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code that you've shown, it looks like you may have a couple of issues, but there may be additional issues related to setup for Stripe Payment.

The process for setting up Stripe within your application is covered here.

## Setup Stripe in your Application

Add Stripe keys to your `config/secrets.yml` file:

```
development:
  stripe_private_key: <%= ENV["STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY"] %>
  stripe_public_key: <%= ENV["STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY"] %>
```

You can keep the STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY and STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY in your environment.  Test and production environments would require similar configuration settings.

Make certain to add this code to your controller, or in any code that you intend to use the Stripe API:

```
require "stripe"
Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.secrets.stripe_private_key
```

## Add a Migration to Add Stripe Customer ID to Customer

This migration provides an example based on a User class; your application may use a different model, so adjust as necessary to fit your purpose.

```
class AddUserStripeCustomerId < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.string :stripe_customer_id, limit: 50, null: true
    end
  end
end
```

## Create a Customer

When you're ready to begin the billing process for a customer, create the customer:

```
if !@user.stripe_customer_id
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => stripe_details[:stripeEmail],
    :source  => stripe_details[:stripeToken]
  )

  User.update(stripe_customer_id: customer)
end
```

Make sure to save the customer ID in your User model.  You'll need to take care to not re-create and overwrite your customer ID for a user, because this is your tie-in to the Stripe payments system for that user.

## Implement the Controller

The form elements (parameters) that you're submitting aren't scoped like a Rails model-based form.  Typically, this is due to using a `form_tag` for a form that's not based directly on a model.  This means that instead of having parameters scoped by a model hash, the parameters are unscoped.

Your strong parameters aren't included here, but they may be part of the issue.  Make sure that you have the `stripeToken` and `stripeEmail` included in the `permit` list, like so:

```
params.permit(:stripeToken, :stripeCard, :stripeEmail)
```

Make certain to *not* include the typical `require` method on the strong parameters, as that validates that the parameters are scoped by a model object.  In your `create` method, you should call the strong parameters method, and use the result, like so:

```
require "stripe"

class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.secrets.stripe_private_key

  def new
  end

  def create
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = 500

    stripe_details = stripe_params

    if !@user.stripe_customer_id
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => stripe_details[:stripeEmail],
        :source  => stripe_details[:stripeToken]
      )

      User.update(stripe_customer_id: customer)
    end

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
      :currency    => 'usd'
    )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end

private
  def stripe_params
    params.permit(:stripeToken, :stripeCard, :stripeEmail)
  end
end
```

## More Information

Also check out [How to create a charge and a customer in Stripe (Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37244061/6263819) for additional details on managing customer accounts and charges with Stripe.

Comment: Hi Michael! Thanks for offering some insight but after updating my controller with your changes I am still getting the 'ERROR TypeError: can't dup NilClass' error. It's really frustrating because I don't even know what it means!

Comment: @FergusMorton I updated the answer to include setup steps, in case you're missing something in the setup/configuration for using Stripe.  This information was in the link that I had provided, but I've moved the relevant portions into this answer.  Please do let me know if you have any questions or difficulties.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for getting back to me. Before I try this solution I was just wondering if publishable key and secret key are the same as private and public key?

Comment: Hi Michael, just implemented your above solution and added what the error log is outputting in my original post. Any ideas?

Comment: @FergusMorton The publishable key is the same as the public key, and the secret key is the same as the private key.  The error that you're seeing now is because you either haven't performed the migration that I described in the **Add a Migration to Add Stripe Customer ID to Customer** section of my answer, or you named the column in your migration something other than `stripe_customer_id`.